# How can I removed a list from the board?

Tags: trello

By mistake a create a new list that I don't need and I want to removed it, delete it, disappear it, from my board. Can somebody let me know how can it be done.

Comment: Are you talking about Trello?

Answer (score 1):

Click on the drop-down arrow in the top-right corner of the list and choose archive list.

Once archived, you can get these items back (this works for cards & lists) by selecting Options -> Archive Items, this displays a list of archived cards with a link at the top to switch to archived lists.

From the unarchive screen you can unarchive or delete cards, but only unarchive lists.